# Sign in with apple in flutter app using parse server says "email in use"

Tags: ios, flutter, parse-platform, parse-server

My problem is I have 6 apps in App Store, they're using 1 core package. Every app is the same but they have other data other package name etc. If I delete my user account from parser and clear my auth settings in apple device - I can login to each app using apple sign in. And everything is good till I'm logged in. When i log out and try to log in again it says "e-mail in use". To login again i have to repeat deleting my account from parser and clear auth settings.

I really don't know how to figure it out, should I change something in flutter code or in parse-server config?

Comment: Would you mind to share the code that you are using to log in the user?

Comment: Yes, here it is @DaviMacêdo:
`final AuthorizationCredentialAppleID credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
  scopes: [AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email, AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName],
);

String? email = credential.email;
String? name = credential.givenName ?? '';
String? famName = credential.familyName ?? '';

ParseResponse response = await ParseUser.loginWith(
    'apple',
    apple(
        credential.identityToken!,
        credential.userIdentifier!
    ),
  email: email,
  username: '$name $famName'
);`

Comment: What is the line of code throwing the error message? Would you mind to share the complete error stack?

Comment: Line which returns server error: `await ParseUser.loginWith(`
Error on server side says: `"{"message":"Account already exists for this username.","code":202,"level":"error","stack":"Error: Account already exists for this username.\n  at config.database.find.then.results (/home/old/multiple-apps-parse-server/node_modules/parse-server/lib/RestWrite.js:589:13)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)","timestamp":"2022-01-10T08:54:24.583Z"}`
Hmm i noticed there can be problem with username, not e-mail as i thought at the beginning. I'll make some fixes and write back